# Ubuntu 14.04 Mate - disable automatic screen lock and "Screen Lock" button over terminal

Tags: lock-screen, mate

How can I disable that Ubuntu locks the screen after 5 minutes and how can I remove the "Screen Lock" button from the menu? I have to do it over a Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

For me with fairly new versions of MATE DevRobot's solution doesn't work, although for all I know for Ubuntu 14.04's version of MATE it could work. For me what works is:

```
gsettings set org.mate.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

Comment: Very good. Still working in Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, and Debian 10

Answer (score 5):

Disable screen lock:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled false
```

Change `Lock=true` to `false`.

I'm not sure how you can remove the screen lock button, but you can open this file and see if it contains a screen-lock section (I don't have mate so I can't say if it is present):

```
sudo -H pluma /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.mate.power.policy
```

If you find it, replace `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>` with `<allow_active>no</allow_active>`.

Comment: I have no (hidden) folder named kde but I was able to find the org.freedesktop.upower.policy file. I will edit it and look if it works.

Comment: @ghostgate oh LOL :D I got mixed up - will edit my answer with mate :)

Comment: @ghostgate answer updated