# How to disable normal user password at lockscreen WITH Black screen at login issue

Tags: login, password, screensaver, username

*I'm still quite a noob. Sorry for my english, not a native speaker.*

It's just to avoid putting password each time my dad laptop goes to sleep (basically used as a home pc and security wouldn't be a problem).

Specifically in his normal user (since I created an admin user for any pursose).

I've already allowed direct access at startup without password but I wondered if it was possible to remove the lockscreen to prompting the password access,
I already tried [this](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/disable-ubuntu-screensaver-password/) by installing [Screensaver Preferences](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/screensaver/start) (absent in this ubuntu 19.10) but it didn't work.

### UPDATE 1

FORGET THAT ANSWER I GAVE...

After a shutting down and starting that pc just shows a black screen instead of a choosing the user to login with.
Fuuu...

### UPDATE 2

I've read this similar [black screen login issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439480/black-screen-instead-of-login-screen) but pressing:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
  or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

  didn't do much for me, at least It appeared the a blinking `_` but I couldn't input anything

So I just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Canc</kbd> and that rebooted the pc.
To my surprise now automatic access worked just fine, so I decided to uncheck the automatic access at login from Settings->Details->Users

Should it all be ok now?
I have already uninstalled the [Screensaver app](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/screensaver/start) with Ubuntu Software Center but maybe it would be better to `apt purge` it (not sure by which name), right?
**OR**
Would it be safer to deactivate lockscreen password from Editor Dconf?
But by searching "screensaver" I don't know which of these three I should modify (and I've no intention of do nothing without any confirm):

- in /org/mate/screensaver/ a toggle for lock-enabled
- in /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver a toggle for lock-enabled
- in /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver (but I don't think this suite my case)

Answer (score 1):

practically the same as you did in **MY SECOND ANSWER**:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

... which is taken from: [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029696/disable-password-request-from-from-suspend-18-04)

* not an answer but I can't comment. sorry

Answer (score 0):

### MY FIRST ANSWER

For the moment I achieved to delete the normal-user password by adapting this [similar case answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281085/) to mine by running this form terminal

```
su - my-admin-user
sudo passwd -d my-normal-user
```

- here's a quote from `man passwd`

> -d, --delete
>   Delete a user's password (make it empty). This is a quick way to
>   disable a password for an account. It will set the named >account
>   passwordless.

which gave me this output

```
passwd: password expiry information changed
```

Not sure it's the best solution for this, but it seems to work fine

### WARNING

Maybe it's best to uncheck Automatic Access before shuttin off/restarting the pc, as I added in question UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

### MY SECOND ANSWER

After adding my [own solution for my specific Black Screen problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/1215754/)

I [found out](https://askubuntu.com/a/685831/) I had to solve the screensaver lockscreen with this simple command line

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled false
```

or with the GUI method, by going to the same path with Dconf Editor and unchecking `lock-enabled`